# How to set background color for UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uipageviewcontroller, xcode7-beta4

How to set color for background view in `UIPageViewController`? Is it possible to do this in Storyboard?

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

edit: I thought the question was about UIPageControl.

You should be able to simply modify the color of the UIPageViewController's view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; //Set to any color.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case, you need to change UIPageControl of UIPageViewCotroller.

Try this.

```
UIPageControl* proxy = [UIPageControl appearanceWhenContainedIn:[self.pageViewController class], nil];
[proxy setPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
[proxy setCurrentPageIndicatorTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[proxy setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

If you project is written by swift, try this.

```
let proxy: UIPageControl = UIPageControl.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses(self.pageViewController.self)
proxy.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
proxy.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
proxy.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Comment: Question is about scrollView color of UIPageViewController, not about UIPageControl.

Comment: The question is,  " How to set the background color of a UIPageViewController "  and not about UIPageControl, please edit your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Inside UIPageViewController's view, you can use this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set backbround color to white
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}
```

I've set the color to white, but you can pretty much insert whatever color you want.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the background color, but it doesn't appear to be exposed in Interface Builder.

Following the proscribed method for setting up the page view controller in IB, you need to:
1. Add a UIContainerView to your view controller
2. Add a UIPageViewController to the storyboard
3. Add a Embed segue from the UIViewContainer to the UIPageViewController (with the identifier myPageViewController)

The from your original view controller, add this to your `prepareForSegue` method:

```
    if ([segueName isEqualToString: @"myPageViewController"]) {
        /* _pageViewController is a property where I keep a reference to the embedded controller */
        if (_pageViewController == nil) {
            /* only do this once */
            _pageViewController = (WePageViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
            _pageViewController.dataSource = ...;
            _pageViewController.delegate = ...;
            _pageViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    }
```

p.s. apologies as I haven't moved to Swift yet...

Answer (score 0):

To change the background colour , use the `UIPageControl` and assign the `backgroundColor` property to the desired `UIColor`

`UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];`